# Is there a SQL window function to use a calculated value from a previous row?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, window-functions

I need to calculate a row's value based on a *calculated* value from the previous row. I'm looking for some window function (or other solution), if there is one, that can help me do this. For context, we have the following data:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE example_data (
    SALES_DATE DATE,
    CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED NUMBER(10,1),
    LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED NUMBER(10,1),
    CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD NUMBER(10,1),
    LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD NUMBER(10,1)
);
INSERT INTO example_data VALUES
('2023-11-01', 1000, 1000, 0, 0),
('2023-11-02', 0,    1000, 0, 0),
('2023-11-03', 0,    1000, 0, 0),
('2023-11-04', 200,  1200, 0, 0),
('2023-11-05', 0,    1200, 0, 0),
('2023-11-06', 0,    1200, 0, 0),
('2023-11-07', 50,   1250, 0, 0),
('2023-11-08', 0,    1250, 0, 0);
```

| SALES_DATE | CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED | LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED | CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD | LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-02 | 0 | 1,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-03 | 0 | 1,000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-04 | 200 | 1,200 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-05 | 0 | 1,200 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-06 | 0 | 1,200 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-07 | 50 | 1,250 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-11-08 | 0 | 1,250 | 0 | 0 |

Each day we may purchase some units `CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED`. The current total units purchased is `LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED`.

> **Note:** `LTD` stands for live-to-date, meaning a running total.

I'm doing some extrapolation and need to calculate the `CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` and `LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` fields (these are predicted units sold, based off below rules).

- `CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` - Predicted units sold for day = 10% of remaining units.
- `LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` - This is running total of extrapolated units.
- Remaining units = `LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED` - `LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` (previous day).

The below `example_data_exected` is the result I'm looking for (Note: this is the data that needs to be created, it is not available. I just created a table to make it easier for you to view).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE example_data_expected (
    SALES_DATE DATE,
    CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED NUMBER(10,1),
    LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED NUMBER(10,1),
    CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD NUMBER(10,1),
    LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD NUMBER(10,1)
);
INSERT INTO example_data_expected VALUES
('2023-11-01', 1000, 1000, 100,  100),   -- 1,000 left
('2023-11-02', 0,    1000, 90,   190),   -- 900 left (1,000 - 100)
('2023-11-03', 0,    1000, 81,   271),   -- 810 left (1,000 - 190)
('2023-11-04', 200,  1200, 92.9, 363.9), -- 929 left (1,200 - 271)
('2023-11-05', 0,    1200, 83.6, 447.5), -- 863.1 left (1,200 - 363.9)
('2023-11-06', 0,    1200, 75.3, 522.8), -- 752.5 left (1,200 - 447.5)
('2023-11-07', 50,   1250, 72.7, 595.5), -- 727.2 left (1,250 - 522.8)
('2023-11-08', 0,    1250, 65.5, 661.0); -- 654.5 left (1,250 - 595.5)
```

| SALES_DATE | CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED | LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED | CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD | LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 100 |
| 2023-11-02 | 0 | 1,000 | 90 | 190 |
| 2023-11-03 | 0 | 1,000 | 81 | 271 |
| 2023-11-04 | 200 | 1,200 | 92.9 | 363.9 |
| 2023-11-05 | 0 | 1,200 | 83.6 | 447.5 |
| 2023-11-06 | 0 | 1,200 | 75.3 | 552.8 |
| 2023-11-07 | 50 | 1,250 | 72.7 | 595.5 |
| 2023-11-08 | 0 | 1,250 | 65.5 | 661.0 |

You can see on the first day, remaining units is whatever was purchased that first day - 1,000 - so 10% of that is 100, and the running extrap live-to-date (LTD) is 100.

On the second day, no units were purchased, so remaining units is 1,000 - 100 (previous day LTD_EXTRAP) = 900. So the extrapolated units for that day is 900 * 0.1 = 90. And the LTD_EXTRAP for today is 100 + 90 = 190.

And it keeps going like this.

I can't figure out any SQL to extrapolate these two fields (`CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` and `LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD`) in a `SELECT`. I tried using the `LAG` window function, but this requires the previous number to be static (I think), or am I missing something about it. Or is there some way I can use an `UPDATE` to update these fields?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using [Databricks SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-window-functions.html), which supports all ANSI-SQL, but also has it's own set of functions available. So a solution using Databricks SQL would also work.

#### UPDATE

Just for reference, this is what I tried with `LAG`, and it didn't seem to work, as it is using the current EXTRAP_LTD (0.00).

```sql
SELECT
    sales_date,
    curr_date_units_purchased,
    ltd_units_purchased,
    (ltd_units_purchased - LAG(ltd_extrap_num_sold, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sales_date)) AS remaining_units,
    (remaining_units * 0.10) as curr_date_extrap_num_sold,
    SUM(curr_date_extrap_num_sold) OVER (ORDER BY sales_date) AS ltd_extrap_num_sold
FROM example_data;
```

And this was the result

| SALES_DATE | CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED | LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED | REMAINING_UNITS | CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD | LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-11-02 | 0 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-11-03 | 0 | 1,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-11-04 | 200 | 1,200 | 1,200 | 120 | 0 |
| 2023-11-05 | 0 | 1,200 | 1,200 | 120 | 0 |
| 2023-11-06 | 0 | 1,200 | 1,200 | 120 | 0 |
| 2023-11-07 | 50 | 1,250 | 1,250 | 125 | 0 |
| 2023-11-08 | 0 | 1,250 | 1,250 | 125 | 0 |

Comment: Have you looked into the LAG function.  Lag retains whatever last record was as comparison for whatever the current records is when processing.

Comment: @DRapp Hmm, I did try it, but maybe I wasn't using it correctly. I thought the value had to already be set _before_ processing. I didn't know it uses an up to date value during processing

Comment: @DRapp I updated with the `LAG` that I tried using. Am I not using this correctly? I feel like I'm not

Comment: Of course, if you `partition by sales_date`, then a record on a different `sales_date` compared to the current row will not be used because it belongs to a different set of the partition. You need to remove that. You may also need to change the function to `LEAD` instead of `LAG` or use a descending order.

Comment: @Atmo Yes, you're absolutely correct about the PARTITION. I don't know why I had that. I just removed it, but still same result. I will look into your other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: And of course, you are getting all these zeroes from the `example_data` table, which I expect will be corrected when you use `example_data_expected` instead.

Comment: @Atmo `example_date_expected` is not real. It's just a table to show what I expect as the result. The two columns I need are not available, they are the values I need to calculate/extrapolate.

Comment: In `example_data`, `ltd_extrap_num_sold` and `curr_date_extrap_num_sold` contain only zeroes, which are now **correctly** returned by your 2 window functions. I do not see what else you expect `LAG`/`LEAD` and `SUM` to return there...

Comment: @Atmo Yes I understand that. I am trying to implement something based off Drapp's comment that said it will use the currently processed value, instead of the static 0. This is what I am trying to do. Maybe he meant using it in an `UPDATE`? I don't know.

Comment: Oh I see. Your question is as unclear as it can get... In fact, `LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED`, `CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` and `LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD` are fields you want to calculate in your result rather than, as you make it look like in your question, columns in a table you want to query data from, is that it? I doubt it is feasible with just a window function; use a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Atmo Yes you got it. And yes, a solution below using a recursive CTE looks like it works. This is actually new concept to me, so I need to dig further into it. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls, see another solution.

```
with params as(select cast(0.9 as decimal(38,10)) x)
,cte1 as(
select t.*
  ,row_number()over(order by sales_date) k
  ,sum(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED)over(order by sales_date) roll_sum_purchased
  ,params.x
from example_data_expected t
cross apply params
)
,cte2 as(
select * 
  ,roll_sum_purchased 
   -  (sum(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED*power(x,1-k))over(order by sales_date)) 
      *power(x,k) extrap_sum
from cte1
)
select SALES_DATE,k,CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED,roll_sum_purchased 
  ,extrap_sum-lag(extrap_sum,1,0)over(order by SALES_DATE) curr_day_extrap
  ,CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD
  ,extrap_sum
  ,LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD
  ,LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD - extrap_sum check_extrap_sum
from cte2
```

Parameter `x=0.9` can be passed in any other way or written everywhere in the request as a constant.
Manipulations with calculation of `power(x,k)` can also be improved.

I add some data to test table

```
INSERT INTO example_data_expected VALUES
 ('2023-11-09', 0,    1250, 58.906521, 719.841311)
,('2023-11-10', 0,    1250, 53.0158689, 772.8571799)
,('2023-11-11', 0,    1250, 47.71428201, 820.5714619)
```

It is advisable to additionally check this values. I'll check with @Saikat query. The discrepancies are satisfactory.

Draft result of query with your and additional data

| SALES_DATE | k | roll_sum_purchased | curr_day_extrap | CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD | extrap_sum | LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD | check_extrap_sum | CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 1 | 1000.0000000000 | 100.000000 | 100.0000000000 | 100.000000 | 100.0000000000 | 0.000000 | 1000.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-02 | 2 | 1000.0000000000 | 90.000000 | 90.0000000000 | 190.000000 | 190.0000000000 | 0.000000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-03 | 3 | 1000.0000000000 | 81.000000 | 81.0000000000 | 271.000000 | 271.0000000000 | 0.000000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-04 | 4 | 1200.0000000000 | 92.900000 | 92.9000000000 | 363.900000 | 363.9000000000 | 0.000000 | 200.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-05 | 5 | 1200.0000000000 | 83.610000 | 83.6000000000 | 447.510000 | 447.5000000000 | -0.010000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-06 | 6 | 1200.0000000000 | 75.249000 | 75.3000000000 | 522.759000 | 522.8000000000 | 0.041000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-07 | 7 | 1250.0000000000 | 72.724100 | 72.7000000000 | 595.483100 | 595.5000000000 | 0.016900 | 50.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-08 | 8 | 1250.0000000000 | 65.451690 | 65.5000000000 | 660.934790 | 661.0000000000 | 0.065210 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-09 | 9 | 1250.0000000000 | 58.906521 | 58.9065210000 | 719.841311 | 719.8413110000 | 0.000000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-10 | 10 | 1250.0000000000 | 53.015869 | 53.0158689000 | 772.857180 | 772.8571799000 | 0.000000 | 0.0000000000 |
| 2023-11-11 | 11 | 1250.0000000000 | 47.714282 | 47.7142820100 | 820.571462 | 820.5714619000 | 0.000000 | 0.0000000000 |

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mPEB7bg1)

Upd1.
About using power().
For purchase 1000 units, extrapolated sales

```
(extrap)=1000*0.1=100 and remains =1000*(1-0.1)=1000*0.9=1000*power(0.9,1)=900.
```

For second day

```
extrap=900*0.1=90 and remains 900*(1-0.1)=900*0.9=1000*0.9*0.9=1000*power(0.9,2)=1000*0.81=810
```

For day `k` remains

```
1000*power(0.9,k)
```

```
tod ->a1,a2,a3 - current day purchased values(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED)  
a1k=1,a2k=4,a3k=7
rest - remains from purchased
LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD - rolling sum =(rolling sum purcased)-rest  
xk=power(x,k), where k - day number  

rest from a1 for first day -> a1*power(x,1) ->1000*power(0.9,1)->1000*0.9=900  
extrap for first day for a1=1000.0-900.0=100  
rest from a1 for day num=k  =a1*power(x,k) ->1000*power(0.9,k)  
rest from a2 for day num=k  =a2*power(x,k-4+1) ->200*power(0.9,k)  
rest from a3 for day num=k  =a3*power(x,k-7+1) ->50*power(0.9,k)  
rest from sum of (a1+a2)  for day number k=4 is  
a1*power(x,k)+a2*power(x,1)  
->a1*power(x,k)+a2*power(x,k)/power(x,1-k)  
->(a1+a2/power(x,1-k))*power(x,k)
->((a1+a2*power(x,k-1))*power(x,k)  
->((a1*power(x,a1k-1)+a2*power(x,a2k-1))*power(x,k)  
Note that for a1 with k=1 a1*power(x,1-k)*power(x,k)  
->a1*power(x,0)*power(x,1)->a1*1.0*0.9
For row with k=7  
((a1*power(x,a1k-1)+a2*power(x,a2k-1)+a3*power(x,a3k-1))*power(x,k)  
Sou: sum(tod*power(x,todK))over(order by ...)*power(x,k)
```

| SALES_DATE | k | xk | tod | rest from a1 | rest from a2 | rest from a3 | rest_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.11.2023 | 1 | 0,9 | a1=1000 | a1*xk=900 | 0 | 0 | 900 |
| 02.11.2023 | 2 | 0,81 | 0 | 810 | 0 | 0 | 810 |
| 03.11.2023 | 3 | 0,729 | 0 | 729 | 0 | 0 | 729 |
| 04.11.2023 | 4 | 0,6561 | a2=200 | 656,1 | 180 | 0 | 836,1 |
| 05.11.2023 | 5 | 0,59049 | 0 | 590,49 | 162 | 0 | 752,49 |
| 06.11.2023 | 6 | 0,531441 | 0 | 531,441 | 145,8 | 0 | 677,241 |
| 07.11.2023 | 7 | 0,4782969 | a3=50 | 478,2969 | 131,22 | 45 | 654,5169 |
| 08.11.2023 | 8 | 0,43046721 | 0 | 430,46721 | 118,098 | 40,5 | 589,06521 |
| 09.11.2023 | 9 | 0,387420489 | 0 | 387,420489 | 106,2882 | 36,45 | 530,158689 |
| 10.11.2023 | 10 | 0,34867844 | 0 | 348,6784401 | 95,65938 | 32,805 | 477,14282 |
| 11.11.2023 | 11 | 0,313810596 | 0 | 313,8105961 | 86,093442 | 29,5245 | 429,428538 |

Note that to use this method, you need to study the effect of the length of the row sequence for calculation. As the value of `k` increases, the used part of the multiplier mantissa decreases. For example, power(0.9,80)=0.000218474500528393.
This can reduce the accuracy of calculations (if you need accuracy).
For example for purchase of 1000 units, after 80 day remains 0.218474500528393 units and extrap is 0,0218474500528393 units.
It just seems that you don't need to use all the amounts `sum(...)over (order by date of sale)` - all rows before. you can `sum(...)over(order by sales_date rows ... nearest 100)`. In this case, same changes in calculations must be done.

Next variant. There should be no problems with the accuracy of calculations.

```
with cte0 as(
select t.*
  ,row_number()over(order by sales_date) k
  ,cast(0.9 as decimal(38,20)) x
from example_data_expected t
)
,cte1 as(
select t.*
  ,cast(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED*power(x,1-k) as decimal(38,20)) dayP1_K
  ,cast(k*log(x) as decimal(38,20)) kxL
from cte0 t
)
,cte2 as(
select * 
  ,sum(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED)over(order by sales_date)  -- roll_sum_purchased
   -cast(exp(log((sum(dayP1_K)over(order by sales_date)))+kxL) as decimal(38,20)) extrap_sum
from cte1
)
,cte3 as(
select *
  ,extrap_sum-lag(extrap_sum,1,0)over(order by SALES_DATE) curr_day_extrap
from cte2
)
```

There used  `equality`

```
x=exp(log(x))
log(x*y)=log(x)+log(y)
log(power(x,k))=k*log(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will take some time review and understand it. Is the 0.9 an arbitrary number, or is it the different between 1 and the 10% (0.1)?

Comment: Yes, 0.9 is pair for 0.1 (90% remains vs 10% sold).

Comment: Hey @ValNik, so testing your answer, I was not able to get it to work because `corss apply` is not something that's supported with Databricks (Spark SQL) - also testing in Snowflake. Could it be written using something more widely supported, and not specific to SQL Server?

Comment: Also another thing I just noticed. The `example_data_expected` is not a table that is available. It is just an example of the data that I expect as the outcome. I see that you are using it in your query.

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced it with `example_data` and it still produced the same result. And I was able to replace `cross apply` with `cross join` and it worked also.

Comment: I like your answer because it doesn't use a recursive cte. Recursive CTEs aren't supported in Databricks (Spark) SQL apparently.

Comment: Just curious, how did you figure out the math in the formulas you used? I would never have thought to use `power()` in any way to solve this.

Comment: You can delete ``cross apply`` or ``cross join`` and replace ``params.x`` with ``cast(0.9 as decimal(38,10)) x`` -  directly use this constant value.

Comment: I'll add some comments about using power() in this case.

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution using recursive CTE in SQL server. But I am not sure about the value that you had at row number 6. A value of 552.8 is correct? If yes, can you please provide the explanation? Please see the approach below. you can tweak the code if you want to run against any of the databases.

```
with base_cte as
(
    select min(SALES_DATE) as minDate , max(SALES_DATE) as maxdate from example_data
) , 
recursive_cte as
(
    select 
        SALES_DATE ,
        CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED , 
        LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED ,
        cast(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED as decimal(10,2)) as PREV_DAY_LTD_EXTRAP , 
        cast(CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED*0.1 as decimal(10,1)) as
        CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD 
    from example_data where SALES_DATE = (select minDate from base_cte)
union all
    select 
        b.SALES_DATE , 
        b.CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED , 
        b.LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED , 
        cast(a.PREV_DAY_LTD_EXTRAP+b.CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED-a.CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD as decimal(10,2)) as PREV_DAY_LTD_EXTRAP , 
        cast((a.PREV_DAY_LTD_EXTRAP+b.CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED-a.CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD)*0.1 as decimal(10,1)) as CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD
    from recursive_cte as a inner join example_data as b on dateadd(day,1,a.SALES_DATE) = b.SALES_DATE
    where b.SALES_DATE <= (select maxdate from base_cte)
)
select SALES_DATE , CURR_DATE_UNITS_PURCHASED , LTD_UNITS_PURCHASED , CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD ,
sum(CURR_DATE_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD) over(order by SALES_DATE) as LTD_EXTRAP_NUM_SOLD from recursive_cte;
```

Comment: Hey @Saikat you're absolutely correct, the numbers I had were wrong. I just calculated them manually and made some mistakes. But your answer has the exact solution I'm looking for. I'm going to wait a couple days until the bounty is available. If no-one provides a better answer, I'll reward you with a bounty. I've been banging my head on this for a few days now. I was thinking about a recursive solution, but couldn't get one to work. Just hope performance isn't too crazy, as this might go into the millions of rows. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: I liked the solution proposed by @Saikat. About ``the millions of rows``. It is unlikely that these millions of rows cannot be divided into parts (partitions). For @Saikat's solution, as well as for other solutions, the size of the partition is more important than the overall size of the table. I think @Saikat can offer a solution where recursion is carried out for each part separately, which will significantly increase performance. It would be nice to additionally describe the possibility of dividing data into parts. I also want to offer a solution that is somewhat different from the above.