# How to Handle SQL case clause for MDT and MST date format to apply condition in date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have to handle scenario if MDT and MST date format data, i would have to handle as below case.

if MDT date format(Mountain Daylight Time), i have to apply case clause for date -1 other wise MST (Mountain Standard Time), let it be the value.

Kindly help me the sample case clause for sql statement to handle date column.

example:

```
select batch_date,column2,column3 from table name.
```

batch_date column sometime MT format or MDT format, so if MDT format, i have do the condition date -1 otherwise lets put MST (Mountain Standard Time) value.

below databricks SQL example, I have tried, kindly validate and give your advice or changes.

```
batch_track_end_date as BATCH_TRACK_END_DATE,CASE WHEN DATE_PART('HOUR', batch_track_end_date) + DATE_PART('MIN', batch_track_end_date) <= 7 THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, batch_track_end_date) AS DATE) ELSE CAST(batch_track_end_date AS DATE) END AS BATCH_TRACK_RPT_DATE
```

Comment: If the timezone is important, why not store your data as a `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: we are migrating legacy system so that we have to find it is it MST or MDT so that apply logic in case statement to format the value

Comment: Ok, post some data and what you want to achieve, and it should be easy to help you Also, how you know if date is MDT or MST. A datetime in sql server doesn't store any information about time zones, so you need some other way to find it, it's not possible just by looking at a date

Comment: Formatting is a task for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer. Like I said, store the value as a `datetimeoffset` and you can then easily tell what timezone the value is for, and therefore what relative time it is.

Comment: date value  now like this 2006-05-01T03:00:00Z
2002-12-20T13:00:00Z

Comment: Ok, one more time... How do you (or us) know if date is A or B?

Comment: lf.batch_track_end_date as BATCH_TRACK_END_DATE,
case when (extract(HOUR FROM batch_track_end_date)+(extract(MIN FROM batch_track_end_date)/60)) <=7 then date_trunc('DAY',date_add(batch_track_end_date,-1)) else date_trunc('DAY',batch_track_end_date) end as BATCH_TRACK_RPT_DATE,

Comment: above one i have to handle MDT or MST

Comment: Please update your **post** with sample data, and tell us how you know if a value is in one time zone or the other.

Comment: change to: `CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, batch_track_end_date) + DATEPART(min, batch_track_end_date) <= 7 THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, batch_track_end_date) AS DATE) ELSE CAST(batch_track_end_date AS DATE) END AS BATCH_TRACK_RPT_DATE`

Comment: is it support databricks sql quey ?

Comment: i got output as below like,

BATCH_TRACK_END_DATE      BATCH_TRACK_RPT_DATE
2002-01-10T05:00:00Z           2002-01-09
2002-01-14T23:00:00Z           2002-01-14

Comment: i need both column so that i added

Comment: select batch_track_end_date as BATCH_TRACK_END_DATE,CASE WHEN DATE_PART('HOUR', batch_track_end_date) + DATE_PART('MIN', batch_track_end_date) <= 7 THEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, - 1, batch_track_end_date) AS DATE) ELSE CAST(batch_track_end_date AS DATE) END AS BATCH_TRACK_RPT_DATE
from tablename

Comment: please help me to validate

Comment: @DeveloperKE Please read this: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html . Specifically for "Offset Z" .

Comment: @siggemannen - i think your solution will be fix my issues, let me test it and confirm to you. mean while give me explanation for your solution, i mean what your did in that query, still i have doubt what is use of <= 7 and date_part for hours?

Comment: I just translated your query to sql server. the logic is all yours.

Comment: Hi if my date value like this 2006-05-01T03:00:00Z, I have to find month MARCH to OCTOBER then needs to do logic Date-1 subtraction, please advice

Comment: @DeveloperKE - You have requested that this question be reopened, but you still have not provided usable sample data and expected results after multiple requests.  I also don't think you have clearly described (in words not code) how you determine if the time is to be displayed in MST of MDT. Again, sample data and expected results would help. Be sure to provide multiple values to cover a variety of cases.

Comment: Perhaps you are not even asking the correct question. How about... **Question:** Given a date/time value in the database stored as UTC, how do I convert to local date/time (MST or MDT) taking into account daylight-savings time? **Answer:**  SQL server has `AT TIMEZONE` operators for this. First to mark the stored value as UTC, apply `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`. Next you can convert to local with `AT TIME ZONE 'Mountain Standard Time'`. This produces a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type. This can be cast back to `DATETIME` to strip off the offset portion.  See [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a338/1).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but the formatting is necessary.

The sql server tag seems to be a complete red herring. Is all your data in databricks, it just happened to originate in SQL Server and now your are migrating?

Please use this as a template, fill it out such that it matches your data **exactly** . If it's stored as a string datatype now, present it as a string. If it's stored as a timestamp with formatting, present it as such. Timestamps are delicate creatures.

Recommended reading: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

```
with some_sample_data as (
  select vals.col1, vals.batch_date
    from values (1, timestamp('2002-01-10T05:00:00+01')),
                (2,  timestamp('2002-01-10T05:00:00Z')),
                (3, timestamp('2002-01-09T05:00:00Z')) AS vals(col1, batch_date)
)
select * 
  from some_sample_data;
```

Run:
select current_timezone()

And provide the result.

Provide the exact output you want to see corresponding to your sample data. Provide this in a formatted markdown table.

When you are filling out the template, making sure it matches exactly with your source data, pay close attention to how someone would differentiate the timezones. If you can't answer that, there's no way you can tell Databricks how to either.

Edit:

Please see this: [Is there a SQL window function to use a calculated value from a previous row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478364/is-there-a-sql-window-function-to-use-a-calculated-value-from-a-previous-row)

as an, in my opinion, exemplary way to pose a question. Completely reproducible sample data, with expected result, code for what has already been tried, and clear natural language describing the problem.