How can I calculate this conditional monthly limit?
In May client P003 had 600 of buy_amt (sum of sales in that period) and 1000 transfer_amt. I want to calculate the remaining limit (buy_amt - transfer_amt) but starting from top to bottom and the deduction only happens if the result is positive.
transfer_amt is ordered by day_time for date. In June client had 600 total buy_amt and 1750 transfer_amt, His total buy_amt is his starting limit (600 for June).

First step is 600 - 1000 = - 400 (negative result, so do not deduct),
600 - 100 = 500 (result is positive so next deduction happens for 500 and not 600),
next is 500 - 300 = 200 (positive) and so on.

When the month ends the last positive remaining_limit for June is transferred to July.



date
buy_amt
transfer_amt
remaining_limit
how it should calculate




30-jun-2024
600
1000
-400 (skipped)
(600 - 1000)


30-jun-2024
600
100
500   Yes
(600 - 100)


30-jun-2024
600
300
200   Yes
(500 - 300)


30-jun-2024
600
300
-100 (skipped)
(200 - 300)


30-jun-2024
600
50
150   Yes
(200 - 50)


…
…
…
…
…


31-jul-2024
100
0
250
(150 + 100)



If the month is not finished, remaining_limit is negative and the client increases buy_amt, then the calculation starts again from the start of the month. Once a month is finished there are no re-calculations.

You need a sequence or timestamp too. As it is now, the order is unknown since several rows have the same date.

While not a duplicate, this question might be food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77478364/is-there-a-sql-window-function-to-use-a-calculated-value-from-a-previous-row

Typical problem where you should use the MODEL clause, you need to prepare your data by adding a pseudo id number sorted by the order of processing you need, that will help you to reference cell of previous row easily. To say it simple: if you can formalize your calculation in a spreadsheet you can do it with MODEL clause. If you need more help, you should just give more detail about the data.

You can do this with a recursive query.  Here's a commented example with results illustrating that it works.  (NOTE: you would comment out the "TEST_DATA" and use your actual database table instead.)
with test_data ( client_id, txn_date, buy_amt, transfer_amt ) as
  ( SELECT 'P003', TO_DATE('30-JUN-2024 08:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P003', TO_DATE('30-JUN-2024 09:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P003', TO_DATE('30-JUN-2024 10:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P003', TO_DATE('30-JUN-2024 11:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'P003', TO_DATE('31-JUL-2024 08:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 50 FROM DUAL ),
-- Actual solution starts here.  ORDERED_DATA CTE just orders the
-- the data 1,2,3,... so that we can easily join each row to the next one
-- WITH
  ordered_data ( client_id, txn_date, buy_amt, transfer_amt, rn ) as
  ( SELECT client_id, txn_date, buy_amt, transfer_amt, row_number() over ( partition by client_id order by txn_date ) rn
    FROM test_data ),
-- REC1 CTE (named "REC1" because it's recursive) starts with the first 
-- row and then recursively gets the next row(s) until it runs out of rows.  Doing it recursively like this is what allows us to do calculations
-- in each row that depend on the rows selected so far, which is what 
-- we need for your conditional running-total logic.
  rec1 ( client_id, txn_date, buy_amt, transfer_amt, rn, remaining_limit_calc, remaining_limit_disp) AS 
  ( SELECT r0.client_id, r0.txn_date, r0.buy_amt, r0.transfer_amt, r0.rn, 
           CASE WHEN r0.buy_amt - r0.transfer_amt < 0 THEN r0.buy_amt ELSE r0.buy_amt - r0.transfer_amt END remaining_limit_calc,
           TO_CHAR(r0.buy_amt - r0.transfer_amt) || CASE WHEN r0.buy_amt - r0.transfer_amt < 0 THEN ' (skipped)' ELSE NULL END remaining_limit_disp
    FROM   ordered_data r0
    WHERE  rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r0.client_id, r0.txn_date, r0.buy_amt, r0.transfer_amt, r1.rn + 1 rn, 
           CASE WHEN r1.remaining_limit_calc - r0.transfer_amt < 0 THEN r1.remaining_limit_calc ELSE r1.remaining_limit_calc - r0.transfer_amt END remaining_limit_calc,
           TO_CHAR(r1.remaining_limit_calc - r0.transfer_amt) || CASE WHEN r1.remaining_limit_calc - r0.transfer_amt < 0 THEN ' (skipped)' ELSE NULL END
    FROM   ordered_data r0 INNER JOIN rec1 r1 ON r1.client_id = r0.client_id AND r1.rn+1 = r0.rn 
    )
-- This just dumps the results.  
select   client_id, txn_date, buy_amt, transfer_amt, remaining_limit_disp
from     rec1 
order by client_id, txn_date;  

Results

+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| CLIENT_ID |  TXN_DATE | BUY_AMT | TRANSFER_AMT | REMAINING_LIMIT_DISP |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| P003      | 30-JUN-24 | 600     | 1000         | -400 (skipped)       |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| P003      | 30-JUN-24 | 600     | 100          | 500                  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| P003      | 30-JUN-24 | 600     | 300          | 200                  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| P003      | 30-JUN-24 | 600     | 300          | -100 (skipped)       |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| P003      | 31-JUL-24 | 600     | 50           | 150                  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------+


It's probably no better than the MODEL solution given.  I just find the syntax a little more intuitive and easy to remember.

First try with MODEL based on what I understood:
with data(client_id, dat, Buy_amt, Transfer_amt) as (
    select 'P003', to_date('30-06-2024 01', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'), 600, 1000 union all
    select 'P003', to_date('30-06-2024 02', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'), 600, 100 union all
    select 'P003', to_date('30-06-2024 03', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'), 600, 300 union all
    select 'P003', to_date('30-06-2024 04', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'), 600, 300 union all
    select 'P003', to_date('30-06-2024 05', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24'), 600, 50
)
select client_id, dat, Buy_amt, Transfer_amt, remaining_limit
from (
    select row_number() over(partition by client_id order by dat) as rn,
        d.* from data d
)
model
    partition by (client_id)
    dimension by (rn)
    measures ( dat as dat, buy_amt as Buy_amt, Transfer_amt as Transfer_amt, 
        0 as remaining_limit, 0 as skipped, 0 as last_positive)
    rules automatic order
    (
        remaining_limit[any] = 
            nvl2(skipped[cv()-1],
                case when skipped[cv()-1] = 1 
                    then nvl(last_positive[cv()-1], buy_amt[cv()]) - transfer_amt[cv()]
                    else 
                        case when remaining_limit[cv()-1] < 0 
                        then last_positive[cv()-1] 
                        else remaining_limit[cv()-1]
                        end - transfer_amt[cv()]
                end,
                buy_amt[cv()] - transfer_amt[cv()]),
        last_positive[any] = case when remaining_limit[cv()] > 0 then remaining_limit[cv()] else remaining_limit[cv()-1] end,
        skipped[any] = case when remaining_limit[cv()] < 0 then 1 else 0 end        
    )
;




client_id
date
buy_amt
transfer_amt
remaining_limit




P003
30/06/24
600
1000
-400


P003
30/06/24
600
100
500


P003
30/06/24
600
300
200


P003
30/06/24
600
300
-100


P003
30/06/24
600
50
150




This is a different aproach to the problem using MODEL clause and takeing care of new buys and months dimension. Didn't quite sure about understanding the recalculation part within the month so this is how I got it and see the solution.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :     (from question)
with tbl ( CLIENT_ID, DAT, BUY_AMT, TRANSFER_AMT ) AS
  ( Select 'P003', To_Date('30-06-2024 03:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 1000 From Dual Union All
    Select 'P003', To_Date('30-06-2024 05:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 100 From Dual Union All
    Select 'P003', To_Date('30-06-2024 10:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 300 From Dual Union All
    Select 'P003', To_Date('30-06-2024 17:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 300 From Dual Union All  
    Select 'P003', To_Date('30-06-2024 21:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 600, 50 From Dual Union All
    --
    Select 'P003', To_Date('31-07-2024 06:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 100, 0 From Dual 
  )

--      S Q L :
Select    DAT, BUY_AMT, TRANSFER_AMT, USED_AMT, REMAINING_AMT
From    ( Select    t.*, To_Char(DAT, 'yyyy-mm') "MM",
                    Min(To_Char(DAT, 'yyyy-mm')) Over(Partition By CLIENT_ID) "FROM_MM",
                    Max(To_Char(DAT, 'yyyy-mm')) Over(Partition By CLIENT_ID) "TO_MM",
                    Count(*) Over(Partition By CLIENT_ID, To_Char(DAT, 'yyyy-mm')) "MAX_RN", 
                    Row_Number() Over(Partition By CLIENT_ID, To_Char(DAT, 'yyyy-mm') Order By DAT) "RN"
          From      tbl t
        )
    MODEL    Partition By  ( CLIENT_ID )
             Dimension By  ( MM, RN )
             Measures      ( DAT, BUY_AMT, TRANSFER_AMT, FROM_MM, TO_MM, MAX_RN, 
                             0 "START_AMT", 0 "NEW_BUY_AMT", 0 "USED_AMT", 0 "REMAINING_AMT")
    RULES  (  NEW_BUY_AMT[ANY, ANY] = Case When TRANSFER_AMT[CV(), CV()] = 0 Then BUY_AMT[CV(), CV()] Else 0 End, 
              START_AMT[ANY, ANY] = BUY_AMT[CV(), 1], 
              USED_AMT[ANY, ANY] = Case When START_AMT[CV(), CV()] + Nvl(Sum(NEW_BUY_AMT)[CV(), RN <= CV()], 0) - Sum(USED_AMT)[CV(), RN < CV()] - TRANSFER_AMT[CV(), CV()] >= REMAINING_AMT[CV(), CV()]
                                        Then TRANSFER_AMT[CV(), CV()]
                                   Else 0
                                   End, 
              REMAINING_AMT[ANY, ANY] =   Nvl(Case When CV(RN) = 1
                                                   Then Nvl(Max(START_AMT)[MM = To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(DAT[CV(), CV()], -1), 'yyyy-mm'), RN > 0] + 
                                                            Sum(NEW_BUY_AMT)[MM = To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(DAT[CV(), CV()], -1), 'yyyy-mm'), RN > 0] -
                                                            Sum(USED_AMT)[MM < CV(), RN > 0] + START_AMT[CV(), CV()], BUY_AMT[CV(), 1])
                                              Else START_AMT[CV(), CV()] + Nvl(Sum(NEW_BUY_AMT)[CV(), RN <= CV()], 0) - Sum(USED_AMT)[CV(), RN <= CV()]
                                              End, 0)
           )
Order By  CLIENT_ID, MM, RN

/*     R e s u l t :
DAT         BUY_AMT TRANSFER_AMT   USED_AMT REMAINING_AMT
-------- ---------- ------------ ---------- -------------
30.06.24        600         1000          0           600
30.06.24        600          100        100           500
30.06.24        600          300        300           200
30.06.24        600          300          0           200
30.06.24        600           50         50           150
31.07.24        100            0          0           250  */

